# Eclipse Ivy plugin says jruby has an unresolved dependency, but jruby 1.6.6 doesn't have any

Tags: eclipse, ivy

I'm getting this error when I try to add jruby as a dependency using the ivy Eclipse plugin:

```
Impossible to resolve dependencies of com.restphone#;working@James-Moores-iMac.local
unresolved dependency: org.jruby.extras#bytelist;1.0.8: not found
```

This is in my ivy.xml:

```
 <dependency org="org.jruby" 
  name="jruby-complete" 
  rev="1.6.6" />
```

And this is in ivysettings.xml:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="chain">
            <ibiblio name="codehaus" m2compatible="true" root="http://repository.codehaus.org/"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

But according to the jruby mailing list, jruby [has NO dependencies for runtime, compile or
test scope](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3552651).

Do I need to give the ivy plugin more information somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's always a good idea to specify a configuration mapping for your dependencies.

The following ivy file worked fine for me. As described, only the ruby jar was downloaded.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.demo" module="demo"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile"/>
        <conf name="runtime" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"    extends="runtime"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
         <dependency org="org.jruby" name="jruby-complete" rev="1.6.6" conf="compile->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Here I have mapped my local "compile" configuration to the default remote configuration. (In a Maven module, the default ivy configuration translates to the "compile" scope).

---

I dug into the [remote POM file](http://repository.codehaus.org/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.6/jruby-complete-1.6.6.pom):

```
  <properties>
    <jar.scope>provided</jar.scope>
    ..
    ..

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jruby.joni</groupId>
      <artifactId>joni</artifactId>
      <scope>${jar.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jruby.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>jnr-netdb</artifactId>
      <scope>${jar.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

All the extra depedencies have been declared in the "provided" Maven scope.

Couple of issues:

1)
In Maven the provided scope is used for jars which are required for compiling **that** module. They do not need to be packaged because they are part of the target runtime environment. Similarily such dependencies are not needed as transitive dependencies for your module and hence don't need to downloaded.

2)
All the jars are all located in the Maven Central repository. The following settings file would retrieve everything, if you chose to omit the ivy configuration mapping

```
<ivysettings>
    <property name="ivy.checksums" value=""/>
    <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="chain">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

3)
The following error is caused by a junk checksum. My provided settings file disables this check... something you are advised not to do on a remote repository

```
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]   problem while downloading module descriptor: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jruby/extras/bytelist/1.0.8/bytelist-1.0.8.pom: invalid sha1: expected=e40ee094403473e43f71e21cf9cbf71f08d2098b computed=a9627bc7e42f886e290985367040794adb676320 (977ms)
[ivy:resolve]       module not found: org.jruby.extras#bytelist;1.0.8
```

Comment: Thanks, I put this info out on the jruby mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Although the JRuby docs may not state a required dependency, it looks as though the repository that you are using does...

You've asked for 'jruby-complete' and if you go and look at this POM you will see its specifying the jruby extras.

One option is to select a different POM file as the basis of your dependency, but a quick fix is to add the attribute transitive="false" to your dependency.

```
<dependency org="org.jruby" 
  name="jruby-complete" 
  transitive="false"
  rev="1.6.6" />
```

Comment: Isn't the <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jruby.extras</groupId> section from http://repository.codehaus.org/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.6/jruby-complete-1.6.6.pom specifying that the jar itself provides jruby-extras?